# Lightning component : Get the id of a record

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

In a lightning component I display a list of articles (Article__c custom object) so I ca see, for example, the name of the article, the price, and a button that I'd like redirect to another component which display the details of the article selected.

For now I'm just trying to get the id of the article, in a basic alert in javascript, but I doesn't work : it says the id is null.

Here is a part of the component :

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="wrappers" type="ListeArticlesWrapper" />
<aura:attribute name="articles" type="Article__c" />

<aura:attribute name="Detail" type="String"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="navigate" type="c:NavigateToDetail"/>

<div class="page">
    <h1>Liste des articles</h1>
    <div class="slds">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                    <th scope="col" class="head"></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="head">Nom</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="head">Type</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="head">Prix</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="head"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrappers}" var="wrap">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">
                            <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!wrap.selected}" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell">
                           <ui:outputText value="{!wrap.art.Name}" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell">
                            <ui:outputText value="{!wrap.art.Type__c}" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell">
                            <ui:outputText value="{!wrap.art.Prix__c}" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell">
                            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" 
                                    onclick="{!c.getDetail}" data="{!wrap.art.Id}">Details</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The associated controller js (with the function getDetail)

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.init(component, event);
},

getArticles : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getArticles(component, event);
},

getDetail : function(component, event, helper){
    var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-data") || event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-data")
    alert('detail article : id = ' + id); //it gives me null
} })
```

Thanks !

**EDIT**

And the wrapper class in case you wonder what is the "art" :

```
public with sharing class ListeArticlesWrapper {
//wrapper pour récupérer les articles selectionnés
@AuraEnabled
public Article__c art {get; set;}

@AuraEnabled
public Boolean selected {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get the id of the object being iterated, you do not need to implement **force:hasRecordId**.It is need only if your component should work in a record's context (eg:Inside Record Detail Page).

Generally to store private data in the HTML element custom data attribute is the standard way used in HTML5.More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

The syntax of using data attributes in HTML should follow this format: **data-* attributes**

So you need to change it like this:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected" 
                                    onclick="{!c.getDetail}" data-recId="{!wrap.art.Id}">Details</button>
```

In the controller, you can access like this:

```
event.target.getAttribute("data-recId")
```

Comment: Thank you @Praveen I can see the Ids ! I'm sorry to bother you but now I try to display the article (so the id) into another component, I just created this subject [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135522/display-data-into-a-lightning-component)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add **force:hasRecordId** interface in your component. After that initialise an attribute like below. Then use the attribute in controller.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
</aura:component>
```

Take note that currently this only works if you are going to use your component in App Builder, and for a record home page in Lightning Experience. For more details you can read about it in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm?search_text=force:hasRecord).

Comment: And then where did I use the attribute  ? In the button ? Thank you